# How can I separate Lexical error from Syntax error in flex & bison?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I want to make simple calculator using bison, and I have one problem.

Here is my code:

flex

```c
[0-9]+[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]* { printerr();  return LEXERR; }
[0-9]*"."[0-9]+[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]* { printerr(); return LEXERR; }
. { printerr(); return LEXERR; }
```

bison

```c
stmt: 
    | err NEWLINE
    | error NEWLINE { yyerrok; }
    | stmt expr NEWLINE  { printf("%d\n", $2); }
    | stmt real_expr NEWLINE { printf("%f\n", $2); }
    ;

err: LEXERR
    | err LEXERR
    ;
```

Even if Lexical and Syntax error occur at the same time, I want only Lexical error to be output.
But now, when ERROR occurs at the same time, both occur.

For example:

```
> %%
lexical error(1:1): %
lexical error(1:2): %
> %%
lexical error(2:1): %
syntax error(2)
lexical error(2:2): %
> 10 * %
lexical error(3:6): %
syntax error(3)
> 10 * *
syntax error(4)
```

I want to print like this:

```
> %%
lexical error(1:1): %
lexical error(1:2): %
> %%
lexical error(2:1): %
lexical error(2:2): %
> 10 * %
lexical error(3:6): %
> 10 * *
syntax error(4)
```

I tried use `yyclearin`, but it didn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You could define your own function `yyerror` and put whatever logic you want there.

Comment: The biggest problem is probably the fact that lexer does not always stay synced with the parser. Parser can request lexer to give it a few tokens ahead of time so even if there is some lexing problem, the syntax error can be about some tokens before that. I think the usual solution is to not print anything in the lexer and allow the parser to generate its error.

Comment: How does it help the users of your language to know which opaque component in your language processor was responsible for detecting a particular error?